# Convert Form name to Form object in c#.net

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

I want to convert the string Form name to Winform Object to show the form.In  project the string form name is getting from database header table and its constructor is get from its detail table.

Here is the table structure

```
   *HEADER TABLE*
    ID,Name

   *DETAIL TABLE*
   ID,Constructor_Name,Constructor_Value
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally. the DB and UI are at such opposite ends that I would recommend *don't* store the actual winform name, but store some string token / enumeration instead, and just use a switch:

```
switch(formName) {
    case "OrderInfo": return new OrderInfoForm(ctorValue);
    case "CustomerSearch": return new CustomerSearchForm();
    // etc
}
```

**in all seriousness**, the above is *not* usually much of a maintenance overhead, and the static typing makes it hard to get much wrong. And it will still work when you refactor or switch to a different UI implementation.

However, you can use reflection. If you have an assembly-qualified name, then:

```
Type type = Type.GetType(name);
```

otherwise, if just namespace-qualified, you should ideally obtain the `Assembly` first:

```
Assembly asm = typeof(SomeTypeInTheSameAssembly).Assembly;
Type type = asm.GetType(name);
```

Then simply:

```
Form form = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(type, ctorValues);
```

Comment: I need small help Assume I stored a Form named Form1.cs in DB I tried as per you said as follows `string strFormName="Form1" Type type = Type.GetType(strFormName); // This is giving null reference can you help me`

Comment: @User Type.GetType won't look in your assembly unless you use the AssemblyQualifiedName, i.e. "SomeNamespace.Form1, SomeAssembly". Otherwise, as above, use `someAssembly.GetType("SomeNamespace.Form1")`

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use reflection to do this.

Use [`Type.GetType(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) to get the `Type` object from its name, and then either call [`Activator.CreateInstance()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) to create an instance, or fetch a particular constructor with [`Type.GetConstructor()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getconstructor.aspx) and then call [`ConstructorInfo.Invoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.constructorinfo.invoke.aspx) to invoke it.

Either way, you'll then probably want to just cast the newly created object to `Form` in order to display it.

One thing to consider is what your constructor parameter types are, and how to associate each constructor parameter with the specific row in the table. Do your forms have multiple parameters? Are there any complex values, or are they all strings, ints etc?

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer.problem is that form having multiple constructor and have both string and integer values.how can i pass constructor values to form object?

Comment: @Vyas: Well you'll need to represent in the database which value has which type, what parameter number it is, and find the right constructor etc.

Comment: I need small help Assume I stored a Form named `Form1.cs` in DB I tried as per you said as follows `string strFormName="Form1" Type type = Type.GetType(strFormName);` // This is giving null reference can you help me

Comment: @User: Your string needs to be fully qualified with the namespace.

Comment: `Jon` Didn't get you can you post a sample please

Comment: @User: Your class is presumably in a namespace (check the namespace declaration). That namespace should appear in your string, e.g. `string formName = "Company.SomeProject.Form1"`

Comment: My name space is `Ping` and my solution Name is also `Ping` so can I write `Ping.Ping.Form1`

Comment: @User: No, the solution name isn't part of the namespace in C#. Just look at the declaration. If you have any further problems, I suggest you ask a new question with *all the relevant context*. Comments aren't really designed for this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17066/discussion-between-user-and-jon-skeet)